# bbdock or bbutton for Debian/Lenny fluxbox?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, launcher, fluxbox

I've been getting into the fluxbox window manager more and more, especially using it's more minimal styles.  Currently I'm just using Debian/Lenny's default setup.

I'm looking for a utility which will put an icon in the "slit" and launch a specific app for me with one click.  I've already discovered "bbrun", but that's a two stage process (bring up dialog, type command or select from pull down).  The old blackbox predecessor of fluxbox had bbdock and bbutton [addons](http://blackboxwm.sourceforge.net/BlackboxAddons#Launchers), which seem to do exactly what I want, but aren't in Debian as far as I can see.

Any suggestions from Debian fluxbox users as to how to achieve one-click launch from the slit would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded and built bbbutton 0.8 from [source](http://bbbutton.sourceforge.net/).  One `#include <stdlib.h>` needs uncommenting.  Works great.